# error: 'x' is not a type where x is constructor argument

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Example {
    //...
    static auto make = []() -> std::shared_ptr<receiveObject> {
        return std::make_shared<receiveObject>(Params::EchoBufferSize);
    };

    static auto recycle = [](std::shared_ptr<receiveObject> o) {
        //nothing for now
    };
    recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject> receivePool(make, recycler);
};
```

But I get

```
In file included from /home/project/AIPTCPClient.cpp:57:0:
/home/project/AIPTCPClient.h:312:57: error: 'make' is not a type
         recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject> receivePool(make, recycler);
                                                         ^~~~
/home/project/AIPTCPClient.h:312:63: error: 'recycler' is not a type
         recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject> receivePool(make, recycler);
                                                               ^~~~~~~~
```

As you can see in [shared_pool](https://github.com/steinwurf/recycle/blob/master/src/recycle/shared_pool.hpp#L91), it requires two funcions, that's why I pass my lambdas. But C++ complain that they should be types. I don't get it. Why a constructor would need a type instead of an object?

Comment: Your code is trying to declare a member function, not a constructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Default member initializer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization) (since C++11) only supports braced-list initializer and equal-sign initializer, but not parentheses initializer; so change

```
recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject> receivePool(make, recycler);
```

to

```
recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject> receivePool{make, recycler};
```

or

```
recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject> receivePool = recycle::shared_pool<receiveObject>(make, recycler);
```